# Merge two columns of dates in the same data set

Tags: sas

I would like to concatenate two columns of the same dataset:

> ```
>     ID      Date1       Date2         
>     001     1-1999            
>     002                 2-2021
>     003                 3-2021     
>     004     03-2019                  
>    ....     .......     ......
> ```

I tried:

> ```
> data out1
>   set out   
>   Test = coalesce(Date1 Date2);
> run;
> ```

but without success.

Any suggestion?
Thank you in advance

Comment: What does 'without success' mean? Do you get an error? Are Date1 and Date 2 character or numeric?

Comment: So, the Test column is empty

Comment: Ok. Do you get an error? Are Date1 and Date 2 character or numeric?

Comment: no, simply it doesn't work. It adds an empty column

Comment: Ok. Are Date1 and Date 2 character or numeric?

Comment: all character variables

Comment: Then see my answer. Use CoalesceC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My 2 suggestions:

1. Make sure that you use the correct function. Coalesce for numeric values, coalesceC for character
2. You are missing a comma between Date1 and Date2.

Do this

```
data have;
input ID $ (Date1 Date2)($);
infile datalines dlm = '|' missover;
datalines;  
001|1-1999 |       
002|       |2-2021 
003|       |3-2021 
004|03-2019|       
;

data want;
   set have;
   test = coalescec(Date1, Date2);
run;
```

Comment: It works nicely with coalesceC!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

`COALESCEC` chooses the first non-missing value in the list of passed values.  Coalescing is NOT concatenation. Concatenation is ["the operation of joining character strings end-to-end"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatenation)

For the case of your data **always** having one of date1 or date2 being missing, concatenation would
have the same result of coalescing.

```
result = cats(date1, date2);
```